# Understanding CGI and SQL security from the ground up

Tags: python, sql, security, cgi

This question is for learning purposes. Suppose I am writing a simple SQL admin console using CGI and Python. At http://something.com/admin, this admin console should allow me to modify a SQL database (i.e., create and modify tables, and create and modify records) using an ordinary `form`.

1. In the least secure case, anybody can access http://something.com/admin and modify the database.
2. You can password protect http://something.com/admin. But once you start using the admin console, information is still transmitted in plain text.
3. So then you use HTTPS to secure the transmitted data.

Questions:

1. To describe to a learner, how would you *incrementally add security* to the least secure environment in order to make it most secure? How would you modify/augment my three (possibly erroneous) steps above?
2. What basic tools in Python make your steps possible?
3. Optional: Now that I understand the process, how do sophisticated libraries and frameworks inherently achieve this level of security?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Security is not a patch job, it's a holistic approach.

Incrementally adding security is **not a good idea**. You should integrate security in your application from the ground up.

The best advice I can give you is to try to think like an attacker. Think to yourself: "If I wanted to do something I'm not supposed to be able to do, how would I do it?"

If you're designing an application which uses a database, we careful not to allow [SQL Injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should also be aware of some of the [most popular web vulnerabilities](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Top_Ten_Project) if you're making a web app.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That second link was really useful. Without much experience, it's hard for me to think like an attacker because I don't know my options, but that link make those options quite apparent.

Answer (score 2):

Non-specific to Python, but any administrative features that offer that level of control over a system should be protected with both SSL and an Authentication and Authorization mechanism (login) *at the very least*.

Answer (score 2):

The very first concern I have is protecting against [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) vulnerabilities.  Next i would be concerned with [Broken Authentication and Session Management](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A3-Broken_Authentication_and_Session_Management).   Most importantly in order to maintain a secure session you **must** use https throughout the entire life of the session.   If you where to spill a password or session id or even a sql query in plain text that would be a bad thing.